# How to differentiate between date formats?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have two date formats :

```
"yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

But when I am trying to parse the date :`"11-05-2021"` , it is not throwing exception for `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format. Below is the thing which I am trying to do :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
try {
    sdf.parse(d);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why it is not giving the exception for `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format . How it can be differentiated between the two formats ?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, it even parses but the result is wrong... Another reason for using `java.time`, better start yesterday!

Comment: I’d use `if (d.charAt(2) == '-')` then it’s dd-MM-yyyy, otherwise it must be the other one.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).